# PHP support for Mssql on windows server

Tags: php, sql-server, php4

My client wants to upgrade this website from php4 to latest version.

But first I have to check website on php4 with a SQL databse.

I googled for it but not getting exact information for below -

Does php4 supports SQL database properly?

Is it good to continue with sql server and php5 in future ?

Comment: What exactly did you google as I managed to find plenty of results

Comment: Can you please share some links here ? In my case all were explainig about PHP5. I want to check for PHP4

Comment: Your site already uses php4 so you know that works.

Comment: No, Right now it's using Mysql. but client has some data in MSSQl so he want to do use that database also

Comment: The manual tells you all you need to know http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php  supported in (PHP 4, PHP 5, PECL odbtp >= 1.1.1)

Comment: Export your Mssql data to Mysql for bright future with php...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

php do support almost all database including mssql.

All you need to do is to just enable it by removing the semicolon from php.ini

Regards

Alok

[sportsafter](http://www.sportsafter.com)